# UPS Tracking API C# Zip code returns blank for origin site

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, ups

I am able to get a response from the UPS API without any issues, but I am not able to get any data for the postal (zip) code from the origin.  It will display the zip code at the arrival destination, but I'd like to grab it from the originating shipping location also.

```
foreach (ShipmentType shipment in trackResponse.Shipment)
{
    foreach (PackageType package in shipment.Package)
    {
        foreach (ActivityType Act in package.Activity)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("City {0} {1}, Date {2}, Time {3}, Status {4}, zip {5}",
                              Act.ActivityLocation.Address.City,
                              Act.ActivityLocation.Address.StateProvinceCode, 
                              Act.Date, 
                              Act.Time,
                              Act.Status.Description,
                              Act.ActivityLocation.Address.PostalCode);                           
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my results:

> City MEMPHIS TN, Date 20180716, Time 103742, Status Delivered, zip 38106
>
> City Memphis TN, Date 20180716, Time 101906, Status Out For Delivery Today, zip
>
> City Memphis TN, Date 20180716, Time 070239, Status Loaded on Delivery Vehicle,
>   zip
>
> City Memphis TN, Date 20180716, Time 054655, Status Destination Scan, zip
>
> City Memphis TN, Date 20180716, Time 054023, Status Out For Delivery, zip
>
> City Memphis TN, Date 20180716, Time 040500, Status Arrival Scan, zip
>
> City Memphis TN, Date 20180716, Time 035000, Status Departure Scan, zip
>
> City Memphis TN, Date 20180714, Time 051500, Status Arrival Scan, zip
>
> City Louisville KY, Date 20180714, Time 050600, Status Departure Scan, zip
>
> City Louisville KY, Date 20180714, Time 011300, Status Arrival Scan, zip
>
> City Houston TX, Date 20180713, Time 220800, Status Departure Scan, zip
>
> City Houston TX, Date 20180713, Time 171949, Status Origin Scan, zip
>
> City  , Date 20180713, Time 172613, Status Order Processed: Ready for UPS, zip

You can see the Zip shows up for the line that says Delivered, but I need the zip from the line that says "Origin Scan".  Thanks.

Comment: What C# library are you using?  Or is this custom?  What API object does `ActivityType` map to so we can look at the docs

Comment: I downloaded the tracking API you can download directly from UPS.  It is definitely an API specific question and I cannot find any documentation at any place that would lead me to a resolution.  I used this guys example code for a basis: http://techfritters.com/tag/ups-web-service-tracking-c/